# Why substitution method does not work for $\int (x-\frac{1}{2x} )^2\, \mathrm dx$?

Tags: integration, problem-solving

Why $$\int \ \left(x-\frac{1}{2x} \right)^2 \, \mathrm  dx$$ is easy to integrate once $$\left(x-\frac{1}{2x} \right)^2$$ is expanded, but impossible using substitution method? (tried 5 different subs but of course that is not the proof that there is no suitable substitution) if mathematical results are independent of the logical methods used to derive them, why something so simple works one way but not the other?

Comment: What substitution did you try and failed?

Comment: _When they exist_, the results obtained following different logical methods should be identical. But it's not because one method succeeds that all other methods must succeed. Sometimes (often times?), there's only one way to ask the right question :)

Comment: There is a reason one is taught methods: they sometimes work. One method for integrals is expand the integrand into a sum of terms, and try to integrate each term individually (it doesn't always work, but being simpler than the whole integrand you might have a better chance to do something, possibly quite different things, for individual terms). In the current case this method calls for working out the square.

Comment: $u=1-\frac{1}{2x}$,$u=(1-\frac{1}{2x})^2$,$u=x+ln x^{-\frac {1}{2}}$ and few other stupid ones, but the problem is that expanding first makes it so easy that no thinking is required where as it is hard to find a proper substitution that easy.

Comment: Another possible method is write this as a rational fraction $\frac{(4x^2-1)^2}{4x^2}$ and apply the arsenal for rational fractions.

Comment: The substitution $u=x$ leaves you with a function which is easy to integrate ...

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen : getting an answer is easy by expanding, but why more effort is required for other methods?

Comment: @Mark, was that supposed to be *humor*?

Comment: Because other methods are made for other situations. If you need to fix a screw, using a hammer won't be the best choice.

Comment: @MarkBennet : but that is the original question with u and x swapped, then there is nothing added by the substitution.

Comment: @Inceptio ..Really??

Comment: @Arjang Maybe what you want to hear is that there is nothing particularly friendly about the function $(x-1/x)^2$ afa the area under its curve is concerned, _unless_ you consider that it is actually the sum of the areas under the curves of simpler functions.

Comment: @Arjang - so we are looking for a substitution which makes this function harder to integrate? The original question suggests that no substitution "works". There are integrals for which this is true in some meaningful sense (eg can't be reduced to some class of elementary functions). For such integrals the trivial substitution does not "work" - this is a different case, and the trivial substitution does "work".

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen : and what makes one or the other? without a test for integration to assign which category should one question belong to or the other on can mistake the screw for nail and vice versa, after all one can hammer a screw, and use a screw driver to drive a nail in, the end result would be almost indistinguishable.

Comment: @Sh3ljohn : Aha, now that clears the fog considerably. If it is possible to identify the intrinsic property that makes one approach leading to more complications then yes, being able to explicitly stating why a method is being used rather than another in some situation would be definitely educational, instead if just being put down to experience or luck.

Comment: @Arjang Did you actually try (the hammer and screwdriver part)? I don't think you would succeed. More seriously, there is an order in methods to apply: try simple things first. If you try to integrate a polynomial using substitution or integration by parts, you're making things unnecessarily difficult (you may or may not succeed, but in any case you are wasting your time). Expanding into terms and trying them individually is one of the simplest things to do; I can't easily think of a case where the expansion is possible but gets you on the wrong track.

Comment: And please keep this in mind (it ought to be taught before going into any of the methods) that, unlike formal differentiation, finding primitives is an art, not a technique (unless one is into the business of implementing the [Risch algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Risch_algorithm), which I suppose is not your case). So be happy when you can, but don't complain when you cannot.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen I totally agree with you.This is the reason why we learn a lot of method for everything because we choose the best one to solve it

Comment: @Arjang Consider all available methods in mathematics/logic. You can surely imagine chaining two methods if the caracteristics of the object being manipulated at the output of the first fits the context required by the second. Now let's agree that a proof is the succession of applied methods. It is, somehow, a _path_ in the digraph generated by all the methods with their "links". The path you want to take with substitution simply leaves you in a context in which there is no other available method to conclude (until proven otherwise).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The situation you describe is not too dissimilar to the following: imagine standing in front of a wall with a few doors in it. You want to go in. At first you don't notice any doors so you wander up and down in front of the wall, until eventually you realize there was a door right in front of you all along. Then since you believe there's only one room inside, you are surprised that there wasn't a door everywhere else on the wall outside. Does this make clearer why your surprise is unfounded?

Put another way, equivalence of any correct route doesn't show existence of any proposed route.

Comment: It is not a surprise that why one method is working where the other does not.There is an algorithm that determines if an integration can be performed using elementary functions to obtain a closed form result. This algorithm is used to do symbolic integration and not look for a closed form when it can be known that a closed form does not exist. Now there seems to be number of "methods" of integration, and which one to use is determined by experience! This is maths, there should be an algorithm that determines which methods can be used, and maybe even why some other method will not yield result.

Comment: That's not true. For example, there is no algorithm which determines whether all other proposed instructions even terminate. http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem

Comment: What is not true? The fact that there is an algorithm that decides if a function has a closed form integral? What does this question has todo with halting problem?

Comment: "This is maths, there should be an algorithm that determines which methods can be used" There are two problems here. (a) There is no clear definition of what it even means for an integral to be solvable by one method. Hence in the comments people suggesting $u=x$. (b) Any general method for integration, M, consists of an arbitrary set of instructions. Determining whether this method works requires solving the halting problem.

Comment: Thank you that is intresting, but how does one gets to "Any general method for integration, M, consists of an arbitrary set of instructions"? Symbolic integration relies on being able to determine wether a closed form exists at all. Or am I missing something?

Comment: There are two notions here which are getting conflated. The Risch algorithm solves the problem of determining whether an integral expressed in terms of some specific elementary functions exists, and also gives an expression for the integral. This is a specific approach/method/algorithm and it works. (Ctd...)

Comment: Similarly "try substituting some finite set of $u(x)$ until the integral is a polynomial" is a specific method, but there's no reason why it should always work. (After all, "jump on a pogo stick 10 times and see if it's a polynomial" is a method too.) By contrast, a completely general set of instructions could be given. Then we wouldn't even be able to tell whether this set of instructions terminated, let alone helped, with some "Does it work?" meta-algorithm.

Comment: @Shakos : Thank you, that completely clarifies your answer, could you please include in the answer. +1